# ionic slider hide next button in last slide ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

ionic slider hide next button in the last slide and hide prev button in the first slide try to implement this using ngIf but it's not working ionic 4

```
<ion-slides #slides>
(...)
</ion-slides>
<button ion-button *ngIf="slides.isBeginning()">prev</button>
<button ion-button *ngIf="slides.isEnd()">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`isBeginning()` and `isEnd()` return **promises** so you need to resolve those. Also we would want to listen to when slides change, we can do that for example with the available method `ionSlideWillChange`. So call a function when slide is about to change and check if the slide is either end or beginning and hide/display buttons according to that.

```html
<ion-slides #slides (ionSlideWillChange)="doCheck()">
```

We use a helper of two boolean flags `disablePrevBtn` and `disableNextBtn`, those we put as the condition for the buttons:

```html
 <button ion-button *ngIf="!disablePrevBtn">prev</button>
 <button ion-button *ngIf="!disableNextBtn">Next</button>
```

We also need to use `ViewChild` to get a reference to our slide, so import `IonSlides` and mark it with `ViewChild`:

```ts
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonSlides } from '@ionic/angular';

// ...

@ViewChild('slides') ionSlides: IonSlides;
```

we probably want to mark the `disablePrevBtn` as initially `true`, and `disableNextBtn` as `false`:

```ts
disablePrevBtn = true;
disableNextBtn = false;
```

And finally the function with the two promises, which both return either `true` or `false` depending on the case. Based on these booleans, we switch the boolean flags.  that keeps track on the slides and toggles the booleans:

```ts
doCheck() {
  let prom1 = this.ionSlides.isBeginning();
  let prom2 = this.ionSlides.isEnd();

  Promise.all([prom1, prom2]).then((data) => {
    data[0] ? this.disablePrevBtn = true : this.disablePrevBtn = false;
    data[1] ? this.disableNextBtn = true : this.disableNextBtn = false;
  });
}
```